# Why is momenergy = mass * (spacetime displacement/proper time for that displacement)?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, mass-energy

[The book that I'm following](https://www.eftaylor.com/spacetimephysics/07_chapter7.pdf), *Spacetime Physics* by Taylor & Wheeler, says that,

> **Statement 6: The momenergy 4-vector of the particle is**
>
> $$\textbf{(momenergy)} = \text{(mass)} \times \frac{\textbf{(spacetime displacement)}}{\text{(proper time for that displacement)}}$$
>
> Reasoning: There is no other frame-independent way to construct a 4-vector that lies along the worldline and has magnitude equal to the mass.

But where is the derivation?

(The entire contents of this book are now available under a Creative Commons license. Feel free to download, print, share, translate, and adapt, as long as you follow the (minimal) requirements of the license.)

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: Please use mainstream terms or perhaps avoid typos.

Comment: The book is legit (see https://eftaylor.com/special.html), and uses precisely that term.  I think it is a bit harsh to expect a newbie to jump between books (particularly from such a good one).  In any case, I consider the quoted text to be self contained.  I just wish I could answer it myself!

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Mainstream terminology is energy-momentum 4-vector or 4-momentum for short... 
But, akin to "space-time", it seems "momentum-energy 4-vector" or "mom-energy 4-vector"  is logical, but not mainstream. Given the now more common signature conventions as +--- or -+++ using x0 (over the new less common +++- using x4), "time-space" is more logical compared to "space-time".

Answer (score 5):

The assertion sounds a bit weird - by saying that the vector lies along the worldline and has magnitude equal to the mass, you've defined it by giving a direction and magnitude. There is no other way to construct that vector, frame-independent or not, because only one vector fulfills the condition.

Showing that the condition is fulfilled is simple. The momenergy lies along the wordline because as a vector it is proportional to the displacement, which of course is just the direction of the worldline. And you should already have seen that proper time is the "spacetime length" of displacement - so that $\textbf{(spacetime displacement)}/\text{(proper time)}$ is a vector of magnitude one. Multiplying by the mass just gets you a vector of magnitude $m$.

Comment: ( )/(proper time) is a simple version of the "4-velocity", which plays the role of the tangent vector to the worldline (along that worldline's time-axis at that event). [In geometric units, we think of the 4-velocity as a unit-vector. But in other units, we multiply by c.] So, the momenergy 4-vector (commonly known as the 4-momentum) is the [invariant-]mass times the 4-velocity.  (By the way, the spatial-component is the relativistic-[3-]momentum and the time-component is the relativistic-energy.)